# Regex in C For Matching

Tags: c, regex

I need to make a regex that can match any alphanumeric string of a length < 99 enclosed by two @. The first character after the '@' can also be '_' which I'm not sure how to account for.
Ex. @U001@ would be valid. @_A111@ would also be valid. However, @____ABC@ would not be valid, and neither would @ABC.

I'm relatively new to regex and noticed that the \z is an unrecognized escape sequence. I'm trying to write it in C11 if that matters.

```
#include <regex.h>        
regex_t regex;
int reti;
char msgbuf[100];

/* Compile regular expression */
reti = regcomp(&regex, "^@[[:alnum:]]@\z", 0);
if (reti) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not compile regex\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: You can use this : https://regex101.com/ as a testing site for regex :)

Comment: xSkrappy Thank you! Edit: It actually looks like the site doesn't support C regex which I believe is different than Python/Java regex. If I'm not mistaken C uses POSIX or something like that.

Comment: Best of luck Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following pattern:

```
^@[_[:alnum:]][:alnum:]{0,97}@
```

Here is a brief explanation of the pattern

```
^                from the start of the string
@                match @
[_[:alnum:]]     match underscore or alpha
[:alnum:]{0,97}  then match zero to 97 alpha
@                match @
```

Code:

```
reti = regcomp(&regex, "^@[_[:alnum:]][:alnum:]{0,97}@", 0);
```

Comment: Still says that \z is an unknown escape sequence for some reason?

Comment: I don't know what `\z` is supposed to mean here.  I will remove it.

Comment: It looks as though it will work. Thanks! In two minutes I can set your answer as accepted. (I think I have to wait because I've recently set an answer to accepted)